# how to open a page in new tab on button click in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to open a page in new tab of browser on button click.

I have searched a lot on google but i couldn't find anything.

Here is my button.

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnNewEntry" runat="Server" CssClass="button" Text="New Entry" OnClick="btnNewEntry_Click" />

    protected void btnNewEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        Response.Redirect("New.aspx");
    }
```

Can you please help me how i can do this ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use `window.open`. Like this:

```
protected void btnNewEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
   this.GetType(),"OpenWindow","window.open('YourURL','_newtab');",true);
}
```

Comment: This is open the page in new window instead of new tab and it is not working in firefox 10.0.2 :(

Comment: Updated the answer. Please try it

Comment: @ Arion its work but this is open the page in new window instead of new tab. so i want open new tab not new window please help.

Comment: This opens a new window in Chrome.

Comment: @Arion This opens a new tab but it gets blocked by Pop Up Blocker. I'm using Chrome. Any solution please?

Comment: use '_blank' instead of '_newtab'

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi I'm facing the same issue of blocker, Did you find any solution?

Comment: @NiravParsana did you try `use '_blank' instead of '_newtab'`?

Answer (score 8):

Why not just call window.open straight from OnClick?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewEntry" runat="Server" CssClass="button" Text="New Entry" OnClick="window.open('New.aspx')" />
```

Comment: What if I'm generating the url to open dynamically in the event handler for the button thats being clicked?

Answer (score 6):

Take care to **reset target**, otherwise all other calls like `Response.Redirect` will open in a new tab, which might be not what you want.

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="openInNewTab();" .../>
```

In javaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openInNewTab() {
        window.document.forms[0].target = '_blank'; 
        setTimeout(function () { window.document.forms[0].target = ''; }, 0);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try This

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use JavaScript for the main form / Button click event. An example is:

```
Context.Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.open('AccountsStmt.aspx?showledger=" & sledgerGrp & "','_newtab');</script>")
```

Comment: thank you, it worked very well for me. I replaced '_newtab' with '_blank' to open the window in new tab.

Answer (score 3):

try this rather than redirect...

```
Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write("window.open('ClickPicture.aspx','_blank')");
Response.Write("</script>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem. Client-side wasn't appropriate because the button was posting back information from a listview.

Saw same solution as Amaranth's on [way2coding](http://www.waytocoding.com/2011/02/open-url-in-new-tab-using.html) but this didn't work for me.

However, in the comments, someone posted a similar solution that does work

```
OnClientClick="document.getElementById('form1').target ='_blank';"
```

where form1 is the id of your asp.net form.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Javascript since code behind is server side only. I am pretty sure that this works.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewEntry" runat="Server" CssClass="button" Text="New Entry" OnClick="btnNewEntry_Click" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"/>

protected void btnNewEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Redirect("New.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this Script  
<script type = "text/javascript">
 function SetTarget() {
     document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
 }
</script>
and 
<asp:Button ID="BTNpRINT"  runat="server" Text="PRINT"  CssClass="btn btn-primary"  OnClick="BTNpRINT_Click" OnClientClick = "SetTarget();"/>    
and 
protected void BTNpRINT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/Print.aspx?ID={0}",txtInv.Text));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your button OnClientClick like so:

```
<asp:Button ID="" runat="Server" Text="" OnClick="btnNewEntry_Click" OnClientClick="target ='_blank';"/>
```

This will change the current form's target for all buttons to open in new tab. So to complete the fix you can then use 2 approaches:

1. For any other button in this form, add to client click a "reset form target" function like so:

```
function ResetTarget() {
   window.document.forms[0].target = '';
}
```

2. Add the same code inside the function inside a setTimeout() so the code will reset the form's target after few moments. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40682253/8445364

Answer (score 0):

Per [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

> Nothing an author can do can choose to open in a new tab instead of a new window.

The browser decides between opening a new tab or opening a new window. You cannot control this as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

In vb.net either *on button click* or *on link button click*, this will work.

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "openModal", "window.open('CertificatePrintViewAll.aspx' ,'_blank');", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

add target='_blank' after check validation :

```html
    <asp:button id="_ButPrint"  ValidationGroup="print" OnClientClick="if (Page_ClientValidate()){$('form').attr('target','_blank');}"  runat="server" onclick="ButPrint_Click" Text="print" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on the ASPX HTML front end to make the button go to a new tab to show page in your ASP.NET site dynamically:

```
        <asp:Button ID="btnNewEntry" CssClass="button"  OnClientClick="window.open('https://website','_blank'); return false;" text="WebsiteName"  runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the url is dynamic and you want to control it in the code behind

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewEntry" runat="Server" Text="New Entry" />

//code behind
var id = 0;
btnNewEntry.OnClientClick = $"window.open('New.aspx?ID={id}')";
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <button type="button">Open new tab</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

You shuld do it by client side. you can place a html hyperlink with target="_blank" and style="display:none".
after that create a javascript function like following

```
function openwindow(){
$("#hyperlinkid").click();
return false;
}
```

use this function as onclientclick event handler of the button like onclientclick="return openwindow()"
You need to include a jquery in the page.

Answer (score -4):

Add_ supplier is name of the form

```
private void add_supplier_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    add_supplier childform = new add_supplier();
    childform.MdiParent = this;
    childform.Show();
}
```