# how to get link to open new tab in browser?

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect, onclientclick

I have a save button that saves all the information the user enters from a form into the database. Once all that is done, I want a new tab to automatically open.

So the code checks if the save is successful then I want the new tab to open.

```
if (NewQuoteID != -1)
{
     Response.Redirect("Printouts/DSVQuotation.aspx?QuoteID=" + NewQuoteID.ToString(), false);
}
```

Code for the save button:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSave" CssClass="btnSaveLarge loading" OnClientClick="return CheckNoOfDetails()" ToolTip="Save Quote" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save"  />
```

This code opens the link on the same tab. How do I get the link to open on a new tab in the browser? I see a lot of examples are setting the OnClientClick to something like this: `OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"`
But I am already calling a method in the OnClientClick

Comment: You could try to set the form's target in the OnClientClick method

Comment: If you are using jQuery you may create an event listener for that button (with client ID) then you can easily do whatever you need on client side. Have you tried that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open a page in new tab on button click in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493901/how-to-open-a-page-in-new-tab-on-button-click-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 OnClientClick="window.open('New.aspx')"
```

But question is duplicated, here is the full answer

[how to open a page in new tab on button click in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493901/how-to-open-a-page-in-new-tab-on-button-click-in-asp-net)

Comment: Should be OnClientClick in this case. OnClick is a server side event.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 string script = "<script>window.open('Printouts/DSVQuotation.aspx?QuoteID=" + NewQuoteID.ToString() + "','_blank');</script>"
```

response.write(script);

Answer (score 0):

if you want open tab after server side save operation is success..

client side :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var openNewTab = function (url) {
        window.open(url);
    }
</script>
```

server side

```
        if (NewQuoteID != -1)
        {
            var url = "Printouts/DSVQuotation.aspx?QuoteID=" + NewQuoteID.ToString();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "openmypage", string.Format("openNewTab('{0}');", url), true);
        }
```

Comment: this works but I have to allow pop ups in the browser. Is there anyway to stop that?