# pop-up new tab in browser for displays another aspx page in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to open a pop-up new tab in browser for displays another aspx page After trigger button click event(Html5).
I have found many ways to do this in JavaScript, but haven't been able to find a way to do it using VB.Net.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        //How to implement code
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493901/how-to-open-a-page-in-new-tab-on-button-click-in-asp-net

Comment: on the answer...i recommend the onclientclick approach rather than the recommended answer...that way you dont have an unnecessary call to the server

Comment: Good point, thanks for that @Ctznkane525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.open` with `_blank` as a parameter. For example:

```
Dim s As String = "window.open('" & url & "', '_blank');"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry. Not enough reputation for upvote. Thank your helped:) -

Comment: Sorry. Not enough reputation for upvote. Thank your helped:) -

Comment: No worries! Good luck and happy coding