# Launch new web page with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start using the same browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, webforms, system.diagnostics

I am new to c# and have created a web form using ASP.NET 4.7.2. One of my buttons links to a url, but when I am in debug mode and click on that, the new tab is opened in Microsoft Edge, which is the default browser on my machine.

Is there a way I can use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` to open a new web page in the same browser I currently am?

Comment: Hope this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493901/how-to-open-a-page-in-new-tab-on-button-click-in-asp-net/10493957

Comment: Did you find a solution using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start?

Comment: Nope. Project aborted.