# RedirectToAction in Loop process [.Net Core 3.1]

Tags: javascript, c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I've been struggling to finish the app I'm developing,

here is the scenario:

1. I have a Razor page where the user will input customer number, Company Code, and Date. Users can input multiple customer numbers and the app will split them by comma.
2. once the user inputted the details a button with asp-action pointed to the action named GenerateSoa, it will run a `foreach` statement that will `RedirectToAction` for every customer that is inputted on the GUI

The problem starts here when the loop runs it only opens one tab even if there are 3 customers inputted.
It should open 3 tabs with their details for 3 different customers. below is my code

I did not however include the SoaLooper `cshtml` file.

SoaController.cs

```cs
public IActionResult GenerateSoa()
{
    ClearAmounts();

    #region Date management for SOA

    // First day of Current Month
    var FirstDateOfCurrentMonth = new DateTime(SD.DateToday.Year, SD.DateToday.Month, 1);
    var PreviousMonthFirstDay = FirstDateOfCurrentMonth.AddMonths(-1);
    var PreviousMonthLastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(SD.DateToday.Year, PreviousMonthFirstDay.Month);

   ****** Ommitted some code *****

    // Get last day of Previews month
    var PreviewsBalanceDate = PreviousMonthFirstDay.Month.ToString() + "/" + 
        PreviousMonthLastDay.ToString() + "/" + PreviousMonthFirstDay.Year.ToString();

    #endregion Date management for SOA

    //SD.GuiCustomerNum = customer.ToString();

    var bsid_unpaid_payments = _context.BSIDs.Where(l => 
       (l.UMSKZ == "" || l.UMSKZ != "C") && l.BLART == "DJ");
    foreach (var payments in bsid_unpaid_payments)
    {
        SD.PAmount += Convert.ToDouble(payments.DMBTR);
    }
    SD.UPTotalAmount = SD.UPAmount - SD.PAmount;

    return View();
}

public IActionResult SoaLooper(string customer, int company, DateTime asof)
{
    string[] customerNum = customer.Split(',');
    SD.GuiCompany = company.ToString();
    SD.DateToday = asof;

    foreach (var item in customerNum)
    {
        SD.GuiCustomerNumSelected = item.ToString();
        RedirectToAction(nameof(GenerateSoa));
    }

    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml

```html
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center border">
        <form method="post" class="col-12 text-center">
            <div class="col-12 border-bottom">
                <h2 class="text-primary">Statement of Account</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 pt-4">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label class="float-right">Customer</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input id="customer" name="customer" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label class="float-right">Company Code</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <select id="company" name="company" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Select a number</option>
                            <option value="2000">2000</option>
                            <option value="3000">3000</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label class="float-right">Statement as of</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input id="asof" name="asof" type="date" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <button type="submit" formtarget="_blank" id="btnCheck" 
                                 class="btn btn-primary form-control" asp-action="SoaLooper">Generate</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `RedirectToAction` doesn't open a new tab, it just returns a status code of 302 to tell the client to redirect. If you really want to open multiple new tabs, you should do something like return a list of urls and then use `window.open` when the page loads.

Comment: @Shoejep: where should i put the window.open?

Comment: Added an answer to explain

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectToAction` doesn't open a new tab, it just returns a status code of 302 to tell the client to redirect.

If you really want to open multiple new tabs, you should do something like return a list of urls and then use window.open when the page loads.

I haven't tested it but you could do something like this:

Add your url to a list:

**SoaController.cs**

```
var newTabUrls = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in customerNum)
{
    SD.GuiCustomerNumSelected = item.ToString();
    
    newTabUrls.Add(nameof(GenerateSoa));
}

return View(newTabUrls);
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    @if(Model?.Any() ?? false)
    {
        @foreach(var url in Model)
        {
            @:window.open(url, "_blank");
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

[how to open a page in new tab on button click in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493901/how-to-open-a-page-in-new-tab-on-button-click-in-asp-net)