# How to open a new url from Action in MVC controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is there a way to open a new window (with external url) from a controller in an ASP.NET MVC / C# app?

If it is in view, this is easy. However, this is in controller.

I have to check some data in action, then decide whether to redirect to another action in the same window, or to an external url with a new window. Currently, I tried to use:

```
return Redirect(ad.AdUrl);
```

but it will show the url in the current window, so the user left the current site, which is not what I wanted.

Thanks

Comment: The new windows would have to be opened by the client. You can send a view containing a script or you can send some data to an existing script that can then open a new window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to open a page in new tab on button click in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493901/how-to-open-a-page-in-new-tab-on-button-click-in-asp-net)

Comment: no, it is not the same. mine is in MVC controller, not triggered by a button.

Comment: As @jmcilhinney has stated above this would need to be performed by the client and not the server, so you would need to control this via the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    bool openExternalUrl = // Your logic to determine whether to open an external URL or not.
    ViewBag.OpenExternalUrl = openExternalUrl;
    ViewBag.AdUrl = "https://google.com"; 
    
    if (openExternalUrl)
    {
        // You can redirect to a different action if needed.
        // return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction");
    }
    
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<!-- Your View Content -->

@if (ViewBag.OpenExternalUrl)
{
    <script>
        window.open("@ViewBag.AdUrl", "_blank");
    </script>
}
```

Here we use JavaScript to open the external URL in a new window (_blank) if the ViewBag.OpenExternalUrl flag is true.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to open a new window (with external url) from a
> controller

Yes, you can try to call javascript from MVC controller action,below is a work demo, you can refer to it:
1.create a string property on your Model.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string JavascriptToRun { get; set; }
}
```

2.bind to your new model property in the Javascript of your view,and create a Javascript function that opens a new window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @Model.JavascriptToRun
        function ShowPopup() {                
            window.open('https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/','_blank');
        }
</script>
```

3.in your controller action, you need to call this new Javascript function:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //do your staff
    bool success = true;
    if (success == true)
    {
        var model = new MyModel();
        model.JavascriptToRun = "ShowPopup()";
        return View(model);
    }
    else
        return RedirectToAction("Privacy");
    
}
```

result:

[image]